# why is gdal error saying file does not exist when file.exists = TRUE

Tags: r, gdal, rgdal

I'm getting this error message and I'm stumped as to why.

```
> gdalwarp("Data/Land_Cover/Northern_Land_Cover_2000/landcover_mosaic_originalCRS.tif", dstfile = "Data/Cleaned_Data/landcover_mosaic_lcc.tif", t_srs = LCC, output_Raster = TRUE, overwrite = TRUE, verbose = TRUE)


Checking gdal_installation...
GDAL version 3.4.0
GDAL command being used: "C:\OSGeo4W\bin\gdalwarp.exe" -overwrite  -t_srs "+init=EPSG:3347" -of "GTiff" "Data/Land_Cover/Northern_Land_Cover_2000/landcover_mosaic_originalCRS.tif" "Data/Cleaned_Data/landcover_mosaic_lcc.tif"
Error in .local(.Object, ...) : 

In addition: Warning message:
In system(cmd, intern = TRUE) :
  running command '"C:\OSGeo4W\bin\gdalwarp.exe" -overwrite  -t_srs "+init=EPSG:3347" -of "GTiff" "Data/Land_Cover/Northern_Land_Cover_2000/landcover_mosaic_originalCRS.tif" "Data/Cleaned_Data/landcover_mosaic_lcc.tif"' had status 1
Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, objecttype = "RasterBrick", ...) : 
  Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file. (file does not exist)
```

Why is it telling me the file doesn't exist when

```
> file.exists("Data/Land_Cover/Northern_Land_Cover_2000/landcover_mosaic_originalCRS.tif")
[1] TRUE
```

?

Comment: What happens if you use the full path by including the drive letter?

Comment: The same thing happens

Comment: See if this is the case https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/ConfigOptions#GDAL_DISABLE_READDIR_ON_OPEN